# Python script distribution on Windows - options to avoid virus false positives?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, antivirus

Turning a .py script into an .exe on Windows seems to always result in false-positive virus detection hits.

There are LOTS of discussion threads about this on stackoverflow and elsewhere.  A real good summary is [here](https://medium.com/@markhank/how-to-stop-your-python-programs-being-seen-as-malware-bfd7eb407a7).

pyinstaller from pip, pyinstaller with local-compiled bootloader, py2exe, and nuitka are the various .exe-builders I've tried so far.  Various build tools result in various hit counts on virustotal.com but it seems there will always be some hits no matter what you do - this is the world we live in.

I understand that signing is an option, though the tool being distributed is free and open-source, so the signing option probably won't be pursued.

Chasing down the antivirus vendors to report false positives each time the script is edited and the .exe is rebuilt doesn't seem like a good use of time.

The question here: is it best to give up on the idea of distributing an .exe?  Is a full python installation on the end user's machine, and then just distributing the .py file, the best way to go?  That option seems pretty heavy-weight and overbearing and prone to more installation issues.  But, if it's the only way to avoid the antivirus dance...?  Or is there another middle option?

Comment: seems like this is an opinion based question?

Comment: I think a big possible part (as I didn't personally have this issue) is either with certain parts of the code, *or* in certain libraries. But I am not certain enough to make a statement about it I suppose.

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh I dont think so, since it is asking a clear question ("how do I avoid false positives"), but the wording could do some work..

Comment: I also didn't have virus errors before (on multiple machines). Only one of them had a problem, so it could also be based on the anti-malware software?

Comment: @ZaidAlShattle That's not how I interpreted it, since OP posted a link on "How to avoid" it already.

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh He mentioned it as an option he won't or can't use, to be honest I don't know if the question has issues or is fine, but at least I wouldn't say it is opinion based. I could be wrong though "I understand that signing is an option, though the tool being distributed is free and open-source, so the signing option probably won't be pursued.

Chasing down the antivirus vendors to report false positives each time the script is edited and the .exe is rebuilt doesn't seem like a good use of time."

Comment: You cannot. Anti-virus software use heuristics to detect *suspect behaviour* of programs and white lists for *well known* programs. And of course there is no hope for your pyinstaller generated program to be a *well known* one. So if it manages to trigger a heuristic rule, you are off...

Comment: As an opinion-based question, I would recommend you to rebuild the bootloader yourself using a different toolchain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be the best option: use the embeddable package as downloaded from python.org.  The official docs spell it out [in the second half of section 4.4.1 of 'Using Python on Windows'](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-application).

In their downloads pages, after selecting a version, you can get to a page like [this (for python 3.10)](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3100/):

[image]

Download the 'Windows embeddable package' for 32 or 64 as needed.  Let's say you extract the downloaded zip to $MYDIR.  Then to run your python script, e.g. from a Windows batch file, you could just have a line like

call $MYDIR\python.exe myscript.py

Zero threats detected on virustotal.com for $MYDIR\python.exe, since it's known and signed and trusted and unmodified.  Just to be sure, I did a Windows scan of the entire directory that contains the batch file, myscript.py, and $MYDIR - no threats detected.

This flow appears to work for this application so far.  Will wait to accept this answer until it's been working for a few days.

The downloaded 32bit embeddable package is 7.1MB and unzips to 15.6MB - not huge, not tiny, but sufficiently small for this particular app.

Does anyone have experience with this embeddable package solution, and might know of any caveats or pitfalls?

Comment: Thank you, this solution worked for me. n+=1 that this is the way to solve it.